# Feature Selection for Ridge Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multiple-regression, cross-validation, ridge-regression

There is a closed-form equation for computing the optimal weight matrix $\mathbf{W}_{\text{optimal}}$ according to the feature matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}$ and the target matrix $\mathbf{Z}$ for ridge regression:

$\mathbf{W}_{\text{optimal}} = (\mathbf{\Phi}^T \, \mathbf{\Phi}+\lambda \, \mathbf{I})^{-1} \; \mathbf{\Phi}^T \, \mathbf{Z}$

Let's say that $\mathbf{\Phi}$ consists of an unknown number of useful and useless features. With the points in $\mathbf{\Phi}$, I want to to cross-validation and compare in the end the optimal weight matrices $\mathbf{W}_{\text{optimal},1} ... \mathbf{W}_{\text{optimal},n} $

Does it make sense to eliminate the useless features before determining the optimal weight matrix for getting a smaller regression error with yet unseen data?
In my opinion, it does, but the effect is negligible.

Explanation:
The closed-form solution has been derived through the following equation.

$\frac{\partial E_\text{D}(\mathbf{W})}{\partial \mathbf{W}} = \mathbf{\Phi}^T(\mathbf{\Phi} \, \mathbf{W}-\mathbf{Z} )+\lambda \, \mathbf{W}  =! \, 0$

This equation tries to minimize the error with respect to the weight matrix $\mathbf{W}$. 
So, the useless features get a weight value of around $0$ independent of any value of $\lambda$ between 0 and 1.
Therefore, I think that the effect of useless features gets nearly vanished and that each $\mathbf{W}_{\text{optimal},i}$ is quite similar to each other.

I am unsure if my chain of thoughts is correct or not.
Therefore, I ask for more opinions. Thank you!

(Yes, I have done some research and come across this [explanation](https://towardsdatascience.com/ridge-and-lasso-regression-a-complete-guide-with-python-scikit-learn-e20e34bcbf0b), I want to make sure that my statement is still correct)

**Update**

Some more background information:
I have a data acquisition system consisting of multiple channels. Let's say I have got 8 channels. 6 of them are broken (=do not work properly and "measure" random numbers), while the other 2 channels are functioning correctly. I calculate from each channel 5 different features. So, I end up with 40 features.

Now, I compute the optimal weight matrix. I use cross-validation with unseen data points (data points measured by the same data acquisition system as before and which have not been used in the determination of $\mathbf{W}_{\text{optimal}}$) and get a mean regression error that is close to the mean cross-validated regression error when I use only the features of the 2 correct working channels.

Is this result just a coincidence, or is this the case in general due to the computation of the optimal weight matrix?

I am sorry if my question is too easy - I had several discussions with other students, and we are all a little bit unsure.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "useless feature" in this model and how you determine which features are useless? That would help us understand your question.

Comment: useless features are values that have nothing to do with the regression problem. Let's say, they are arbitrary numbers.

I would determine useless features with Pearson's correlation coefficient or Spearman's rank coefficient.

Comment: Unfortunately, "nothing to do with the problem" is not operationally useful or meaningful.  Even when you introduce perfectly random numbers as a "feature," it typically will be associated--if just a little bit--with the response variable, even after for controlling for all the others.  Moreover, using correlation coefficients to identify such features is guaranteed not to work when there are many variables: that's one reason why model identification is a challenging problem.

Comment: Some background information: 
I have a data acquisition system consisting of multiple channels.
Some of these channels are not functioning properly. Therefore, the features which I calculate out of the incorrectly working channels have no significance. If I compute W_optimal with the useful and useless features and calculate with W_optimal and unseen data new prediction values, the regression error (prediction to target) is nearly equivalent if I redo this procedure only with the valuable features. I wonder if this is always the case or if it was just luck.